# Pass batch file ECHO into PUSHD command prompt command

Tags: windows, command, pipe, prompt

I have a windows batch file, which outputs directory path, e.g.:

```
@echo c:\windows
```

I would like to pass this string "c:\windows" into PUSHD command. I tried this:

```
path.bat | PUSHD
```

but it errors out with "The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.".

Please help.

The solved command prompt log would look something like:

```
c:\>path.bat | PUSHD
c:\Windows>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basic idea (you will need to make appropriate adjustments):

```
for /f %i in ('path.bat') do pushd %i
```